# MySQL - two conditions together at same time

Tags: mysql

Please, I need to print records that meet 2 conditions at the same time:

```
meta_key = '_tribe_wooticket_product' AND meta_value = 1109 
meta_key = '_tribe_wooticket_checkedin' AND meta_value = 1
```

[image: database structure]

thank you all for your time

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    where (meta_key = '_tribe_wooticket_product' AND meta_value = 1109) 
        OR (meta_key = '_tribe_wooticket_checkedin' AND meta_value = 1) 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key)=2";
```

Comment: When you use `COUNT()` it will aggregate all the results into a single row.

Comment: If you just want those two rows, get rid of the `HAVING` clause.